# Is VMware Fusion 5.0.5 compatible with OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, vmware, compatibility

I'm currently running OS X 10.9.5 on my MacBook Pro along with VMware Fusion 5.0.5.  I want to upgrade to OS X EL Capitan. Will version 5.0.5 of VMware Fusion be compatible?

Comment: Officially, only VMware Fusion 8 is supported under OS X EL Capitan although VMware Fusion 7 may install it is not officially supported and there may be issue.  If you're upgrading then you might as well purchase VMware Fusion 8 to run under OS X EL Capitan.

Comment: As VM host software needs to mess with kernel things rather intimately your best bet is to always assume that they will need to be upgraded when upgrading OS X:

Comment: One of the upgrades to OS X explicitly disabled my vmware fusion installation.  As vmware did not offer a cheap upgrade for existing customers, I went with virtualbox instead.

Answer (score 6):

According to the following VMware kb article: [System requirements for VMware Fusion (2005196)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005196) VMware Fusion 5.0.x is not compatible with El Capitan as hosting OS.

After upgrading to El Capitan you need at least VMware Fusion 7.x.

> Fusion 5.x
>
> Any 64-bit capable Intel Mac (compatible with Core 2 Duo, Xeon, i3, i5, i7 processors or better)
> Mac OS X 10.6.7 Mac OS X 10.8 or Mac OS X 10.9, either Client or Server
> ...
>
> Fusion 6.x
>
> Any 64-bit capable Intel Mac (compatible with Core 2 Duo, Xeon, i3, i5, i7 processors or better)
> Mac OS X 10.7, Mac OS X 10.8 or Mac OS X 10.9, either Client or Server
> ...
>
> Fusion 7.x
>
> Any 64-bit capable Intel Mac (compatible with Core 2 Duo, Xeon, i3, i5, i7 processors or better)
> Mac OS X 10.8 or later
> ...
>
> Fusion 8.x
>
> Any 64-bit capable Intel Mac (compatible with Core 2 Duo, Xeon, i3, i5, i7 processors or better)
> Mac OS X 10.9 or later
> ...